# I have installed extension for sorting product by quantity, it show above mention error?

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, magento

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setStoreId() on boolean in /home/zohaibs4/public_html/includes/src/__default.php:7032

Comment: Can you post your script here so that we can check where exactly the error is?

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open includes folder in root and replace code :

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
 With  define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```